# How to change the color of only one button?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a problem. I made a loop with buttons in HTML. So now I want them to change the color when I press the button. But I have the problem that they all change the color. But I only want to change the color of the button that was pressed.

HTML

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let friend of friendsList">
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src={{friend.img}}>
      </ion-avatar>
      <button ion-button color="rank" class="avat"> </button>
      <h2>{{friend.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{friend.status}}</p>
      <button (click)="toggleNamedColor()" ion-button round color="rank" [color]="ionicNamedColor" item-end>+Add</button>

    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
```

TS

```
public ionicNamedColor: string = 'rank';

public toggleNamedColor(): void {
      if(this.ionicNamedColor === 'rank') { 
        this.ionicNamedColor = 'primary'
      } else {
        this.ionicNamedColor = 'rank'
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the code of your loop as well? Anyways you could basically iterate through every button inside of your loop and style their colors directly instead of using variables.

Comment: Can you use it like `<ion-item *ngFor="let friend of friendsList">
        <button (click)="toggleNamedColor(friend)" ion-button round color="rank" [color]="friend.ionicNamedColor" item-end>+Add</button>
      </ion-item>` and then in ts change friend.ionicNamedColor

Comment: @XYZ could you help me with the TS section I don't know exactly what to change to friend.ionicNamedColor. Because when I change this.ionicNamedColor, there is an error (friend before the dot) is red underlined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it like this example by adding color property to the object and change  color property of that object on click

```
 <ion-list> 
    <ion-item *ngFor="let friend of friendsList">
          <ion-avatar item-start>
            <img src={{friend.img}}>
          </ion-avatar>
          <button ion-button color="rank" class="avat"> </button>
          <h2>{{friend.name}}</h2>
          <p>{{friend.status}}</p>
          <button (click)="toggleNamedColor(friend)" ion-button round color="rank" [color]="friend.ionicNamedColor" item-end>+Add</button>

        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>
```

And in ts

```
public toggleNamedColor(friend): void {
      if(friend.ionicNamedColor === 'rank') { 
        friend.ionicNamedColor = 'primary'
      } else {
        friend.ionicNamedColor = 'rank'
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with index in ngFor

**Html**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let friend of friendsList;let i = index">
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src={{friend.img}}>
      </ion-avatar>
      <button ion-button color="rank" class="avat"> </button>
      <h2>{{friend.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{friend.status}}</p>
      <button (click)="curIndex = i" ion-button round [color]="curIndex == i ? 'rank' : 'primary'" item-end>+Add</button>

    </ion-item>
```

declare this variable in .ts file

```
curIndex:number = null;
```

Refer stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-c7lufc?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)